# Can't connect to mongodb on pi locally - can connect remotely

Tags: mongodb

I have mongodb installed on my pi successfully for a few months. 
Since yesterday, I've not been able to connect to it from the local machine, but bizarrely I can connect to it from another machine on the same network.

If I connect locally, I get this

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.1.1-pre-
Sat Sep  3 17:20:39 versionCmpTest passed
Sat Sep  3 17:20:39 versionArrayTest passed
connecting to: test
Sat Sep  3 17:20:39 creating new connection to:127.0.0.1:27017
Sat Sep  3 17:20:39 BackgroundJob starting: ConnectBG
Sat Sep  3 17:22:47 Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:91
Sat Sep  3 17:22:47 User Assertion: 12513:connect failed
exception: connect failed
```

Whereas remotely, it works fine

```
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.9
connecting to: 192.168.1.6:27017/test
2016-09-03T18:43:20.705+0100 D NETWORK  [thread1] creating new connection to:192.168.1.6:27017
2016-09-03T18:43:20.705+0100 D COMMAND  [ConnectBG] BackgroundJob starting: ConnectBG
2016-09-03T18:43:20.709+0100 D NETWORK  [thread1] connected to server 192.168.1.6:27017 (192.168.1.6)
2016-09-03T18:43:20.717+0100 D NETWORK  [thread1] connected connection!
Server has startup warnings: 
Sat Sep  3 17:16:46 [initandlisten] 
Sat Sep  3 17:16:46 [initandlisten] ** NOTE: This is a development version (2.1.1-pre-) of MongoDB.
Sat Sep  3 17:16:46 [initandlisten] **       Not recommended for production.
Sat Sep  3 17:16:46 [initandlisten] 
Sat Sep  3 17:16:46 [initandlisten] ** NOTE: when using MongoDB 32 bit, you are limited to about 2 gigabytes of data
Sat Sep  3 17:16:46 [initandlisten] **       see http://blog.mongodb.org/post/137788967/32-bit-limitations
Sat Sep  3 17:16:46 [initandlisten] **       with --journal, the limit is lower
Sat Sep  3 17:16:46 [initandlisten]
```

I've been tearing my hair out for the last few hours trying to get it to work.

FWIW the only other change I've made to the box is I've installed a wifi dongle a few days ago, but mongo was working fine with it until yesterday

Comment: It looks like mongo is listening on 192.168.1.6, but not 127.0.0.1. Run a "netstat -anp" to see what IP addresses (and ports) mongo is listening on. 0.0.0.0 would be shown to mean all IP addresses the device has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the problem wasn't anything to do with mongo. Pinging localhost and 127.0.0.1 were not completing successfully

I had edited the /etc/network/interfaces file and, for some reason, removed the entry for lo

so, adding back in the lines below and rebooting solved the problem

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```